# Unit Testing show output

Tags: unit-testing

I searched for unit testing tool and I found the suitable one is NUnit and I think it good but my problem that this tool only show test method result only (pass or fail) and I need to show not only pass or fail also the output .How can I show the output using NUnit or if there another unit testing tool its also good ?If its not supported please suggest me how can I solve it.

All ideas are welcomed

Answer (score 5):

Piping the output of System.Console will work for NUnit, but it's not your best option.

For passing tests, you shouldn't need to review the console output to verify that the tests have passed.  If you are, you're doing it wrong.  Tests should be automated and repeatable without human intervention. Verifying by hand doesn't scale and creates false positives.

On the other hand, having console output for failing tests is helpful, but it will only provide information that could otherwise be inferred from attaching a debugger. That's a lot of extra effort to add console logging to your application for little benefit.

Instead, make sure that your error messages are meaningful. When writing your tests make sure your assertions are explicit. Always try to use the assertion that closely fits the object you are asserting and provide a failure message that explains why the test is important.

For example:

```
// very bad
Assert.IsTrue( collection.Count == 23 );
```

The above assertion doesn't really provide much help when the test fails. As NUnit formats the output of the assertions, this assertion won't help you as it will state something like "*expecting <True> but was <False>*".

A more appropriate assert will provide more meaningful test failures.

```
// much better
Assert.AreEqual(23, collection.Count, 
               "There should be a minimum of 23 items by default.");
```

This provides a much more meaningful failure message: *"Expecting <23> but was <0>: There should be a minimum of 23 items by default.*"

Comment: After seeing your response I'm wondering if I misunderstood, does he want the output he produces in his code or the output of the test? It does just say the output so I may have assumed output in general.

Comment: I thought it was general output, too.  My point is if you have to rely on general output because pass/fail isn't enough, you should rethink your testing approach.

Comment: No I need my output not general output.You are correct Jesus and I try to test it

Comment: Really Bryan? Sometimes I need more information than "my test is failing, go fish".  Do you write integration tests? Would you like to know why they fail, not just the details of the exception that was raised?

Comment: Warren my answer was directed at Unit Tests (class / method) level tests with clear expectations and detailed assertions -- you should not need to inspect the output to verify the test manually. In the 5 years since my answer, most modern test runners include output from loggers in the test output, so it's really a moot question at this point. Regardless, how would test output help you in ways that proper assertions cannot?

Comment: I stumbled upon your answer and it helped me greatly. I have a alot of configuration files, that I need to verify. Here the messages made perfect sense, since i could output the file that failed. This meant i could create one unit test, that would look through all the files, instead of creating a unit test for each file, that would essentially all do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

On the bottom bar of NUnit you can click Text Output and that shows all debug and console output.

Comment: ok when I call method getEmp(10) it will return Emplyee object with firstname & LastName & job & age &.... all its members.That's I need

Comment: you can use System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write or System.Console.WriteLine to write out to the NUnit Text output with whatever information you feel is necessary.

Comment: Can I get properties of the returned object as I didn't know the object.I need to print all properties inside the object(employee or company or ...)

Comment: If the properties are private you can use Reflection to get the fields or properties and print them as long as you have the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where are you want to output the data from a test.
I believe you mentioned something another from `File, Log, Console, Debug` output. 
As an alternative `NUnit` allow to output any message in the regular tests output stream, just use following utility methods:

For successful test

```
Assert.Pass( string message, object[] parms );
```

For failed test

```
Assert.Fail( string message, object[] parms );
```

More details see [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.5)

Comment: These methods ends the test.

Answer (score 0):

This post is loooooong after the question was asked, but wanted to chime in.  Yes, you can accomplish a lot in unit/integration tests and probably do most of what you need.  So, I agree, do as much as you can in your test methods.

But sometimes, providing some output is useful.  Especially if you need to further verify the results and that verification cannot be accomplished via your unit test.  Think of an external system that your dev/test environment has no or limited access to.

As an example, let's say you are hitting a webapi to CREATE a claim and the response is the new claim number. But the api does not expose methods to GET a claim, and you need to verify some other data that was created when you made the webapi call.  In this case, you could use the outputted claim numbers to manually check the remote system.

FWIW